# Subscription of products on AceShop (Joomla extension for OpenCart)

Tags: php, opencart, joomla2.5

I am trying to modify AceShop module (extension OpenCart in Joomla) such that subscription facility is provided to users on some specific products. The default functionality of AceShop is straightforward one-time order, but I want my shop to have some specific products that can be subscribed by the user as well. I know that payment gateways like Paypal and Authorize.net provide subscription facility, but I want my shop to keep track of those subscribed products, so that notification is sent to the subscribed users 5 days prior to their order that needs to be shipped and hence they could change the subscription details.

In case of credit card charging gets failed, user is informed and if the subscription is still placed, system again tries to charge from the credit card after some defined period. Order completion invoice is sent each time the credit card gets charged, not for the first time only.

Out of confusion, I want to know if there is a way to do, and I am thinking in a right direction.

Worse thing is that AceShop documentation is only available for people who have a paid subscription. http://www.joomace.net/support/docs/aceshop

Comment: It would be even better if there is any extension available for OpenCart for this feature which I am unable to find.

Comment: @PeterStuart shame on the self reference to OpenCartPlus - it stucks big ass. I wish I could down vote your comment.

Comment: Have you considered looking at a different shopping cart for Joomla that already supports subscription management? Other than the alternatives already mentioned, that might be a viable option for you.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for way more than you can post on StackOverflow. In order to handle recurring charges, you will want to use a merchant services provider that offers recurring billing like authorize.net or Paypal Payments Pro. If you store the credit card information and try to handle the billing on your end you are asking for problems. Not only is it way more complicated, but you open yourself to liability issues related to storing credit card numbers. If the merchant services provider found out you are storing credit card numbers you would likely lose your account.

That said, there are a couple of recurring payment extensions already available for OpenCart that you could be able to install.

http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension&filter_search=recurring

There are probably more, but this what I found on the first search.

Answer (score 0):

Which is it that you are trying to modify?  AceShop COMMERCIAL extension, or OpenCart NON-COMMERCIAL component?

Because it's a commercial product, I'm not sure whether you would be violating any licensing terms by modifying the AceShop component.  And modifying the OpenCart component, while technically allowed, might be rendered inoperable if/when AceShop adds support for a more up-to-date version of OpenCart.

I've read that the AceShop support is pretty responsive.  Have you asked them whether this capability is something they would consider adding to their core product?